# Extracting data from JSON returns undefined

Tags: json

I'm receiving data from a server and I'm trying to get a specific value from it.

The data is received in a variable called body. Here's what I've done:

```
console.log(body);
console.log(body._id);
console.log(body["_id"]);
```

And here is the output:

```
{"__v":0,"name":"asd","address":"asd","coords":[42,52],"dateTime":"2017-12-31T23:59","_id":"5968c7e244d4c66abdb3370b","comments":[],"tags":["asd"]}

undefined

undefined
```

The file definitely has a key called '_id' so why can't I retrieve its value?

Comment: you need to parse JSON with `JSON.parse` first. You are trying to access `_id` attribute of a string

Answer (score 1):

You need to parse the JSON into an object first.

```
var parsedBody = JSON.parse(body);
console.log(parsedBody);
console.log(parsedBody._id);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/evdL198d/

Comment: Don't need parsing